# How can add markers on real time on Google maps Android studio

Tags: java, android

[I am using fragments, I want that every time the fragment is restarted add markers from a list that I have in a database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgHMn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgHMn.png)

Comment: Please, [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Instead copy the [relevent code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) directly in the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

Call your logos() method inside onResume() of Fragment, like following :

```
 @Override
 public void onResume() {
     Log.e("DEBUG", "onResume of Fragment");
     logos();
  }
```

Also remove static from method defination.